# Optocoupler circuit accept input between 3-50 volt

Tags: opto-isolator

How can an optocoupler be used in order to accept a voltage range for example between 3-50 volt to a digital input pin of 3 volt like on the Raspberry?

What would a typical circuit look like in order to drive the optocoupler? Would a simple voltage divider be good enough or is there other more robust ways?

Comment: It can't. Optocouplers use infra-red LEDs which require 1.2 to 1.4 V to turn on. You will also have to allow some voltage drop across the current limiting circuit. Explain what you are trying to do and we may have other ideas for you.

Comment: @Transistor my goal is to have the input isolated and handle 1-50 volt

Comment: 1 volt won't be enough to turn on the optocoupler (unless you also have some other power source besides the signal, and condition the signal, which is what I'd recommend). If you shrink the range to 3-50V then it's definitely possible.

Comment: @anrieff ok changed to 3 volts. It will be ok!

Comment: @www: "*My goal is to have the input isolated and handle 1-50 volt.*" I got that from the title. What is the real problem you are trying to solve? What is your 1 - 50 V input signal? Is there power available on the input side?

Comment: @www.jensolsson.se how fast does the thing need to switch?

Comment: Is there a threshold, above which you expect action A, and below which you expect action B?

Comment: @MarcusMüller 1 second is ok so not fast

Comment: @analogsystemsrf not really, but I guess somewhere at 0.5 - 1 volt or something like that would be suitable.

Comment: @www.jensolsson.se standard question: what's the reason you're optocoupling? Do you *really* need to optocouple? Also, how fast does your signal raise?

Comment: @MarcusMüller The reason is that I would like to be able to accept a signal from another system and this other system is X. I don't know much about it. I dont know if the systems will share a common ground and I dont know what kind of noice I will get from the system X, so hoping with optocoupling to reduce the risks of this. Also if I get 10 000 volts into the input I hope that the rest of the system will survive. I hope that this is a good reason to use an opto coupler so that I have not made a false asumption.

Comment: that is a *very* good reason! This would all be easy if you could assume you had a somewhat reliable power supply on the "dangerous" side, because then you could amplify a signal too weak to drive an optocoupler directly first, and possibly even clean it up a bit first :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A large voltage range can be accommodated by using Vin to drive a constant current source.

Voltages below the minimum forward voltage of the optocoupler's IR diode could be accommodated by using a boost converter to up-convert the lower voltages - but this is best avoided unless the very low voltages are essential.

Here is a conceptual circuit diagram - which would work as is in most cases.
Component values can be adjusted to suit.
Vin is taken to be 3V to "more".
How high "more" is depends on the power rating of R2 and the voltage rating of Q2 and R2.

When voltage is applied Q2 is turned on by R2.
Current in R1 rised until Q1 is turned on when R1 drops about .6V.
Q1 now clamps the base of Q2 at a level that maintains its turn on voltage.
Current drawn I= V/R = 0.6V/R1 , which here =
0.6/100 = 6 mA (approximately).
This current can be changed by changing R1 to suit the optocoupler requirements.

Lower optocoupler currents ease the dissipation requirements discussed below.
Deep-ending on your source a low Iin may be essential.

At 3V in, V_Q2_b = Vb1_Q1 + Vbe_Q2 ~= 1.2V.
So V across R2 ~= 3Vin - 1.2V = 1.8V.
Ib_Q2 = Vr2/R2 = 1.8/10000 ~= 0.02 mA
To support the required 6 mA in this case Beta_Q2 must be IC_Q2/Ib_Q2
= 6 mA / 0.02 mA  = 300.
R2 can be made smaller to increase I_R2 and so reduce the required beta of Q2.

I specified a BC337-40 for Q2 as they are low cost, widely available and have guaranteed beta of 250 - 630 and typically 400.
At Vin of 3V operation is marginal at beta = 250 and reducing R to say 6k* would be wise.

[**BC337**](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/BC338-D.pdf) data sheet.

The BC337 is rated at Vceo of 50V so is marginal at 50V (but *probably* OK - but ...). A surface mount version with identical specifications is available (except for dissipation).

---

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=https%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fF2wjA.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

At Vin = 50V, dissipation in R2 = V^2/R = 2500/10k = 1/4 W.
Using at least a 0.5W part is indicated and 1W "won't hurt".
If R2 is reduced power consumption should be checked.

Q2 max dissipation ~= Iopto x Von = 6 mA x 50C = 300 mW.
C337 TO92 package has a thermal resistance Rtja = 200 C/w.
At 300 mW temperature rise is 200 x 0.3 60C which is "not nice" but OK.

---

If you really want good operation across the maximum possible range something like the (almost magical) PNP Diodes Inc [ZXTN25100DG](https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/ZXTN25100DG.pdf) at under $US1 in 1''s ex Digikey, will do the job with ease. This is in a SOT223 surface mount package but is easily used on strip board or as a through hole part with mounting pins.
Beta, dissipation and operating voltage are higher than for the BC337. What's not to like - apart from the still reasonable price?

Also look at the SMD only NPN SOT23 insanely high dissipation rating [ZXTN25100DFH](https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/ZXTN25100DFH.pdf)  - but the ZXTN25100DG is much nicer to use.

Comment: Thanks for this great reply including explanasion of the circuit. I will take some time to grasp this. A first question I have is that I am used to optocouplers having two sides. I guess you have just left out the part of it that will receive the light and open/close. Correct?

Comment: @www.jensolsson.se Yes -  I just showed the input side of the optocoupler

Comment: I have done much the same to keep led strings locked at 13. 5 ma for constant brightness. I used a MJE340 npn, T0-126 pkg, 300 volt rating instead of the BC337.

Answer (score 0):

If load on the input is not important then a 5W resistor in series with the OPTO isolator LED that is selected (say 1kOhm) to provide the maximum permissible continuous current at 55V would probably do the job.

The current transfer ratio will usually improve (4 times from 50ma to 5mA in the linked paper) with lower drive current and largely compensate for the reduced drive.

The drawbacks of this simple solution include cost and size of and dissipation at high input voltages from the 5W resistor, increased load at high input voltages, lack of protection from excess voltage, lack of reverse voltage protection, lack of ESD protection, high stress on the LED at the maximum voltage, lack of protection from high impedance stray input voltages causing false indication.

The other answer with current limiter solves a number of these issues.  A small HV input LDO regulator configured as a current source might serve the same with half the parts but would need to be examined to see what the minimum drop out is for low input voltages.

[Current Transfer Ratio (CTR) and Response Time of Photocouplers / Optocouplers](https://%20https://www.renesas.com/us/en/products/interface/optoelectronics/current-transfer-ratio-ctr-and-response-time-photocouplers-optocouplers)